# Why does the electrometer measure not the potential of the capacitor plate to which it is connected, but the potential difference between the plates?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage

Here is a picture of the experimental setup. The electrometer shows the potential difference between plates A and B. But why? Shouldn't it show the potential of the plate A to which it is connected? Please explain why this is happening?

P.S. The question may seem silly, but I really want to understand the physics of these processes
[image]

Comment: It seems like plate B is grounded, i.e. 0V by definition. Then the potential of plate A = potential difference between the plates.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot measure the electric potential at a point, because that is a meaningless quantity. You can only ever measure an electric potential *difference* (i.e., a voltage), so in this experiment you must be measuring the electric potential of plate A relative to *something*. Given the diagram, you can see that the meter is measuring the electric potential of the plate *relative to ground*, and that plate B is connected to ground, and so the meter is measuring the electric potential difference between plates A and B.

Answer (score 2):

Electrometers (voltmeters) measure the potential difference between two points, which is why it has two leads.

The diagram shows both plate B and one terminal of the electrometer (voltmeter) connected to what appears to be a common conductor (indicated by ground symbols) which, in turn, appears to be insulated from the capacitor plates. Since the other lead of the electrometer is connected to plate A, That puts the electrometer across the capacitor plates thus measuring the potential difference between them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asked to measure your height with a tape measure you measure the distance between your feet and the top of your head, ie between two positions.

The same has to be done when you are measuring potential **difference**.
The electrometer measures the potential difference between two positions which in this case is the left hand plate $A$ and the ground.
Because the right-hand plate $B$ is connected to the ground the electrometer is  therefore measuring the potential difference between the two plates.